# Distinguish origin of password prompts

Tags: passwords, web-browser, phishing, package-manager

I am wondering how to distinguish (password) prompts that the OS issued from prompts that are delivered application-side. This question first occurred to me when considering Firefox master passwords, but it just occurred to me that installing packages over `apt` may raise the same question (e.g. when the installation process takes some while)

```
[sudo] password for <user>:
```

I see nothing preventing attackers to include such a prompt in their package installation scripts. Do I have that correct (this is interesting especially for AUR packages/Arch Linux, I believe, and any other package source that is not implicitly trustworthy)?

Apart from reviewing the package source, is there any other reliable method to distinguish the origin of a prompt, e.g. viewing a specific log?

Comment: Any package will ask for password if it needs elevated privileges. I'm not sure if `apt` is a good example for your first question.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your question. What is your distinction between a password being prompted "by the OS" vs. "by an application"? The example you show is, in fact, *not* a prompt by the OS, but by an application called `sudo`.

Comment: You are right, I was a bit unclear by it. What I meant is, how do I tell whether I am prompted for the password because the install script uses `sudo`, or whether the author included a custom prompt to catch and somehow exfil the password.

Answer (score 1):

> I see nothing preventing attackers to include such a prompt in their package installation scripts. Do I have that correct (this is interesting especially for AUR packages/Arch Linux, I believe, and any other package source that is not implicitly trustworthy)?

That is correct. Any application can print that message and take a password prompt in response.

Any application can also run the real `sudo` command with a malicious input, for example to install a backdoor or password-stealing malware. You should take that into account.

> Apart from reviewing the package source, is there any other reliable method to distinguish the origin of a prompt, e.g. viewing a specific log?

While the prompt is happening, you could check the list of active processes, for example with `ps a`, and verify that there is in fact a `sudo` command running (with the correct full path to `sudo` as it's installed on your machine).

After the prompt finishes, it depends on your system where the logs may be kept. For example, on Ubuntu, they are logged through `journalctl`. (However, malware could delete those logs once it gets root access.)